# Quotient of $[-1,1]$ homeomorphic to unit circle

Tags: general-topology, quotient-spaces

Let $I:=[-1,1]$ and $Q$ the quotient space where we identified $-1$ and $1$. Show hat $Q$ is homeomorphic to the unit circle $S^1\subseteq \mathbb{R}^2$.

My first idea was to define $g\colon I\to S^1$ by $x\mapsto (\cos(2\pi x), \sin(2\pi x))$, but then the map $f$ satisfying $g=f\circ p$, where $p$ is the quotient map, seems not to be injective. Any hints?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

$$x \mapsto (\cos(\pi x), \sin(\pi x))$$

Comment: Thanks! I can see that the induced map $f$ is continuous and bijective. How do I show that this is an open map?

Comment: Compact -> Hausdorff

Comment: Can you please provide some more details? I am pretty new to topology... Which space is compact? And what do you mean with the arrow? Not all compact spaces are Hausdorf right? And how does this help?

Comment: "Compact -> Hausdorff" is the mnemonic for the theorem that if you have a continuous bijection from a compact space to a Hausdorff space, then it is a homeomorphism.

Comment: Thanks! And $Q$ is compact because it's the image of $I$ under the continuous function $p$ and $I$ is compact? And $S^1$ is Hausdorff because it's a subspace of $R^2$ which is Hausdorff?

Comment: Yes, and yes.${}$

Answer (score 2):

I'm pretty sure you can show that $I=[-1,1] \approx [0,1]$, say by $h : [-1,1] \to [0,1]$ s.t. $h(-1)=0$ and $h(1)=1$. A common way to show that some quotient space $X/{\sim}$ is homeomorphic to a top. space $Y$ is by exhibit a quotient map $q : X \to Y$ which makes same identification as projection map $p : X \to X/{\sim}$. In your case define $q : [0,1] \to \Bbb{S}^1$ by $s \mapsto e^{2\pi is}$.
$\require{AMScd}$
\begin{CD}
I @>{h}>> [0,1]\\
@VpVV @VVqV\\
I/{\sim} @>>> \Bbb{S}^1
\end{CD}
Since $q \circ h$ is a quotient map that makes same identification as $p$, then $I/{\sim}
 \approx \Bbb{S}^1$ by [Uniqueness of Quotient Topology](https://books.google.co.id/books?id=ZQVGAAAAQBAJ&pg=PA71&lpg=PA71&dq=lee+topological+manifold+characteristic+property+of+quotient+map&source=bl&ots=xRo6sruErS&sig=9eiVJmAj1GCyZbgS-Soy2pQ2HFI&hl=en&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwjd6ITepMncAhVaf30KHSdJDbgQ6AEwBXoECAUQAQ#v=onepage&q=lee%20topological%20manifold%20characteristic%20property%20of%20quotient%20map&f=false).